# Is the order of cashed writes preserved in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, file-io

When writing to a file in Windows 7, Windows will cache the writes by default. When it completes the writes, does Windows preserve the order of writes, or can the writes happen out of order?

I have an existing application that writes continuously to a binary file. Every 20 seconds, it writes a block of data, updates the file's Table of Contents, and calls `_commit()` to flush the data to disk.

I am wondering if it is necessary to call commit, or if we can rely on Windows 7 to get the data to disk properly.

If the computer goes down, I'm not too worried about losing the most recent 20 seconds worth of data, but I am concerned about making the file invalid. If the file's Table of Contents is updated, but the data isn't present, then the file will not be correct. If the data is updated, but the Table of Contents isn't, then there will be extra data at the end of the file, but since it's not referenced by the Table of Contents, it is ignored when reading the file, and we have a correct file.

Answer (score 0):

The writes will *not* necessarily happen in order.  In particular if there are multiple disk I/Os outstanding, the filesystem/disk driver may reorder the I/O operations to reduce head motion.  That means that there is no guarantee that data that is written to disk will be written in the order it was written to the file.

Having said that, flushing the file to disk will stall until the I/O is complete - that may mean several dozen milliseconds (or even longer) of inactivity when you application could be doing something more useful.

Comment: RE Stall for milliseconds: That's part of the reason I'm asking this question. On Windows 7, `_commit` takes up to 100 ms. I was hoping that I'd be able to remove this delay and let Windows take care of it, but based on your answer, I won't be able to do that.

Comment: You could always use a database like sqllite at which point the management of the transactions is handled for you.